# Migrating SQL Server tables data from one application to another totally different application tables

Tags: t-sql

We are migrating a few tables' data from one application to another application. These two applications are totally different tables and schema.

We have created general T-sql scripts and temporary tables to store the required data to transform the data in an acceptable format of destination application tables.

Checking here, is there any different approach that we can adapt to migrate the data between the different applications?

Thanks in advance,
Venkat

Comment: As I understand you want to migrate few tables from one database to another database on same of different server. Please confirm if I'm right.

Comment: To a different database server and totally different tables structure. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one-off migration that's a good way. For continuing movement of data from a source to destination system e.g. OLTP system to a data warehouse, a proper ETL tool (SSIS/ BIML) would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need to accomplish the two main options I would suggest are using SSIS to transform and move the data or writing T-SQL scripts like you mentioned to convert data to the proper table structures. If this would be a ongoing migration using ETL tools may be a better option to creating scripts.
I had a similar task of moving data from an older application into a newer one. Since this needs to be done manually by someone, I opted to avoid using SSIS and instead wrote t-sql scripts which use staging and mapping tables to convert the data to the newer table structures. It depends what you are comfortable using.